# js рекурсия и объекты

Tags: javascript, объекты, рекурсия

```
let a = {
    lentgh: 2,
    0: false,
    1: {
        lentgh: 3,
        0: false,
        1: false,
        2: {
            lentgh: 2,
            0: false,
            1: false 
        }
    }
}
```

На выходе должны получить: false, false, false, false, false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменил false на строки, чтобы было понятно, что всё работает.

```js
function process(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') return [obj]; // крайний случай, не объект
  let res = [];
  for (let i=0; i<obj.lentgh; ++i) {
    // рекурсивно собираем скаляры в массив
    res = res.concat(process(obj[i]));
  }
  return res;
}

let a = {
    lentgh: 2,
    0: '0',
    1: {
        lentgh: 3,
        0: '1.0',
        1: '1.1',
        2: {
            lentgh: 2,
            0: '1.2.0',
            1: '1.2.1' 
        }
    }
};
console.log(process(a))
```

Если починить свойство length, можно прозрачно преобразовывать объект в массив:

```js
function process(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') return obj; // крайний случай, не объект
  return Array.from(obj)
    .reduce((c, item) => 
        c.concat(process(item)), []);
}

let a = {
    length: 2,
    0: '0',
    1: {
        length: 3,
        0: '1.0',
        1: '1.1',
        2: {
            length: 2,
            0: '1.2.0',
            1: '1.2.1' 
        }
    }
};
console.log(process(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = {
    lentgh: 2,
    0: false,
    1: {
        lentgh: 3,
        0: false,
        1: false,
    }
}, parseData = (object, parsed = []) => {
  Object.keys(object).forEach(e => {
    if (!isNaN(+e)) {
       if (typeof object[e] === "object")
            return parseData(object[e], parsed);
        
       parsed.push(object[e]);
    }
  });
  
  return parsed;
}

console.log(parseData(a));
```